# Recursively search cell for each value within an array and return position within array

Tags: google-sheets

I have a bunch of transaction descriptions, and I'd like to check against an array for any matches (case insensitive, in any position within the cell) and return the associated position within the array when successful.

I'm looking to use an array of text values and search a cell for each value within the array, returning the position within the array as the "found" result, on Google Sheets.

For example, I have a budget spreadsheet, with a series of transactions, like:

```
COLES - Visa Purchase
WWW.ALHGROUP.COM* ME&U - Visa Purchase
MY BUNNINGS - Visa Purchase 
ALH VENUES - Visa Purchase
ALDI STORES  - Visa Purchase
QUIKSILVER - Visa Purchase 
ALDI STORES  - Visa Purchase
COLES EXPRESS - Visa Purchase
```

and I have a named range ("categories") of

| search_val | return_cat |
| --- | --- |
| Woolworths | Groceries |
| Coles | Groceries |
| ALH | Pub |
| Aldi | Groceries |
| Bunnings | Home |

So, basically I want Google Sheets to search my transaction list for any of the items within `search_val` (not case sensitive, and in any position of the cell - so similar to an `iferror(search(search_val,A1))` and return the position within the array so I can lookup the `return_cat`.  Is this possible?

So I'd end up with

| transaction | return_cat |
| --- | --- |
| **COLES** - Visa Purchase | Groceries |
| WWW.**ALH**GROUP.COM* ME&U - Visa Purchase | Pub |
| **ALH** VENUES - Visa Purchase | Pub |
| MY **BUNNINGS** - Visa Purchase | Home |
| **ALDI** STORES - Visa Purchase | Groceries |
| QUIKSILVER - Visa Purchase | *Not found* |
| **ALDI** STORES - Visa Purchase | Groceries |
| **COLES** EXPRESS - Visa Purchase | Groceries |

Many thanks! My first time in WebApps, let me know please if you think this belongs in another exchange.

Comment: In other words, for "**QUIKSILVER - Visa Purchase**" should the result cell be empty? Or you want see "Not found"? For empty result you can try `=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A1),LOWER($F$2:$F$6)),$G$2:$G$6,"")))` (if table *search_val/return_cat* is in range **F1:G6**)

Comment: Wow, yes that's exactly what I'm looking for!  I don't think I can mark it as answered as it's a comment, but thanks very much.  I'll have to do a bit of research of the different functions to understand what you did!  Ta

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the first table in D1:E and the second table in A1:B. Try the following formula in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,D2:D)),D2:E,2,),"Not found")))
```